# TFS template rule on Area Path

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2017 Update 3 on premise. I have the ability to edit the process template for our projects, and wish to make a change to the area path. I wish to implement a rule on the Area Path to prevent it from being left as the root project name when a new feature/story/bug/task is created. I've tried to use PROHIBITEDVALUES with the root path explicitly stated, but when I save the template I get the following error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Work Item Type: Bug

TF26062: Rule '' is not supported for the field 'System.AreaPath'.

### There were validation errors. Continuing to save may cause the file to become unloadable, do you want to continue?

### Yes   No

If I click Yes, I then get:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Failed to save the 'Bug' Work Item Type to the server.

### TF26062: Rule '' is not supported for the field 'System.AreaPath'.

### OK

So my question is, what rule can I apply to the Area Path field to prevent users from saving work items with the root/default area?

Comment: @Mods - can someone fix my XML formatting for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test all the existing rules are not available for the **System.AreaPath** filed. No built-in rules to validate the **Area Path**.

However you can follow below steps to change the default **Area Path** to prevent it from being left as the root project name when a new feature/story/bug/task is created.

1. Navigate to  Settings --> Work --> Areas
2. Click the link:  **the default team's settings**.
3. Area --> Default Area --> Change --> Select the specific area -->
   Set

---

**Besides**, if you want to validate the Area Path, as a workaround you can create a new field to assist on that, you can refer to this article for details: [Work Item Rules Workarounds: Validating Area Path](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teams_wit_tools/2009/02/07/work-item-rules-workarounds-validating-area-path/)

[image]

Comment: This isn't a good solution for us, as we have a lot of child/grand-child areas. If I set a new default that's not the root, they'd just leave that as the area instead.

Comment: @spikey_richie So, what about the `Area Path validation` workaround?  The **Area Path** filed is a `TreePath` type of field, you can select the specific area path directly from the existing area path list. And the value of the field is REQUIRED. If you specify an nonexistent area path, then you cannot save the work items.